# Vector Question | Is it correct to assume perpendicular distance?

Tags: vectors

I had this question in one of my past papers:

> The position vectors of the points A, B, C, D are
> **OA= i +j + 3k, OB = 3i + 4j +5k, OC= -i +3k and OD = *m*j +4k**
> respectively where *m* is a constant.

(i) Show that the lines AB and CD are parallel when *m*= 3/2

(ii) Given that *m* is not equal to 3/2, Find the shortest distance between the lines AB and CD

For part ii, I made a rough sketch and deduced that the shortest distance between the lines must be the perpendicular distance between them. With that assumption, I had to find the value of *m* and since I have already assumed that it's perpendicular, I used the dot product formula and got the value of m as -4/3. I then used the distance between two lines formula and got my final answer as √2. The answer was correct but it left me wondering whether this assumption of "perpendicular distance" was correct or did I get the answer right purely based on luck?

Comment: perpendicular from any point is the shortest distance between parallel lines. if lines, are not parallel, it's a different story

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The perpendicular distance is always the shortest if the lines don't intersect.

To prove this, suppose we have two lines $L$ and $M$ in space. Assume they don't intersect each other. We can re-orient the lines so that one of them, say $L$ is horizontal from our point of view and an arbitrary point $p$ on $M$ is directly above a point on $L$. Compare the distance from $p$ along the line that goes directly down to $L$ with the distance from $p$ to any other point on $L$. By the triangle inequality, we know that this distance is the shortest from $p$ to $L$.

The same process can be applied to any point on $M$. By reversing the roles of $M$ and $L$ we can see that the distance from any point on $L$ to $M$ must also be on a segment perpendicular to $M$.

Therefore, the minimum distance between $L$ and $M$ will be the length of a segment that is perpendicular to each.